# Android Threads are automatically suspended

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, runnable, executor

I'm trying to make some calculations using Multi threading. At maximum I will have to make 100 different calculations. Even when I tried to balance the start of threads from 10 each time, I am having messages of threads suspending on Log Cat. I think this is killing the performance. When I just launch 10 threads the performance is good.

```
//launch thread for each accuracy values
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100/accuracyInterval);

        int countThreads = 0;

        for(Integer acc: listAccuracies){

            Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(acc);

            if(accuracyInterval != 10) {

                if (countThreads == 10) {

                    while (threadsDoneCounter < 10) {

                        //Log.d("THREADS ","WAITING");

                    }

                    countThreads = 0;
                }

            }
            executor.execute(worker);

            countThreads ++;
        }


        executor.shutdown();

        // Wait until all threads are finish
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

        }
```

Now the code for MyRunnable

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final int accuracy;

        MyRunnable(int accuracy) {
            this.accuracy = accuracy;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("THREAD " , Integer.toString(accuracy) + " START");

            try {

                calculatePrediction(accuracy);


            } catch (Exception e) {


            }


            threadsDoneCounter++;

            Log.d("THREAD " , Integer.toString(accuracy) + " END");

        }
    }
```

What can do make it have a better performance when i have to launch for example 100 threads? what i am doing wrong?

Thanks for the attention,
Regards

Comment: Why would you launch so many threads?!

Comment: I need 100 different calculations. I can lauch 10 threads each time for example. Making this calculations single threaded takes too long.

Comment: 100 threads will make it slower because they'll just fight each other for use of the CPU and waste tons of memory -- unless you have a CPU with 100 cores. (As you've discovered.) "If two is better than one, then one hundred must be better than ten" is false.

Comment: I know. But can't i through ten threads and when that ten finish launch another 10? that's what im trying to do.

Comment: No. Launch ten threads and code those threads to do whatever you need them to do and stop when they're done.

Comment: Stop() is deprecated, should i use interrupt() instead?

Comment: No, no. Don't "reach in" and try to make a thread do the right thing. Code the threads to do the right thing in the first place.